# Apple Magic Keyboard connected in Wired mode - turn Bluetooth off

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth

Is it possible to turn Bluetooth off when connecting Apple Magic Keyboard over Lightning cable? I would like to use it in wired mode and don't want to empty and charge the battery all the time. Furthermore it would reduce electric smog.

Does the keyboard keep broadcasting Bluetooth when wired, or does it disable the keyboard's Bluetooth?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it works well when connected via Lightning cable only with Bluetooth disabled or enabled. I just tested it.

By the way, the keyboard charge lasts about 3-4months with everyday typing. 5min charge can last you hours. The Magic keyboard's battery last much, much longer than previous editions.

Comment: Tested this on an M1 machine and does not seem to be working (or working anymore)

Comment: @MariusPop weird, still works for me every time. Is it an original Apple cable or aftermarket? Not sure why it wouldn't work except a faulty cable or keyboard. :(